# How to know the maximum local memory size that can be used in FPGA kernel (using oneAPI SYCL or OpenCL)?

Tags: opencl, fpga, intel-oneapi

There is a big difference between the document provided through the vendor document and the program output, and I don't quite understand how the local memory is used in the FPGA.

The FPGA I am using is Intel Stratix 10 GX 2800 and according to the [document](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683423/23-2/embedded-memory-features.html) there are 47.25-Megabit (Mb) eSRAM blocks of on-chip memory resources but according to my program the output of local memory is only 16KB.I would like to know the relationship between on-chip memory, local memory and FPGA SYCL kernel.

SYCL Query input:

```
std::cout << "Local memory size: "
          << device.get_info<sycl::info::device::local_mem_size>()
          << std::endl;

std::cout << "Global memory size: "
          << device.get_info<sycl::info::device::global_mem_size>()
          << std::endl;

std::cout << "Global memory cache size: "
          << device.get_info<sycl::info::device::global_mem_cache_size>()
          << std::endl;
```

Query output:

```
Local memory size: 16384
Global memory size: 34359737344
Global memory cache size: 32768
```

For example, when creating an array in the SYCL or OpenCL kernel, what memory affects the maximum size of this array?

Comment: "Document" and "documentation" are two words with radically different meaning in the English language.